# select list in webform containing the list of node titles

Tags: webforms, entities

how can we create a select list in webform containing the list of node titles of specific content type.

I have a product content type through which I have added several product nodes. Now I want to create an inquiry form which should allow the visitors to select the *products from the select list about which they want to send inquiry.

*the products in the select list will be the product node titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out https://groups.drupal.org/node/71588 for providing dynamic select options to the webform module. You'll have to specify the content type, but here's a query that can be used to populate it (replace product with the machine name of the content type):

```
SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE type = 'product' AND status = 1 ORDER BY title ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

[Webform Views Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views_select) is designed for this.

> This module will let you populate a webform select component with data from a view.

Answer (score 0):

[Webform References](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_references) is another option for this.

> Provides a webform component that can reference a node/term/user in webform. It provides "Select List", "Autocomplete", "Checkbox" and "Radio" as widget.

A view with entityreference display can also be used to get the list as options.