# Adding webform component in site factory

Tags: webforms

Hi i am new to Drupal and got stack, I have to add a select list to the webform the select list has product list, I have a content type product. I used Entity reference and webform refernces modules but unable to make it.With using entity reference module i am able to get the product list but how will i add to the webform as a select list field.I am currently working on site factory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [select list in webform containing the list of node titles](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90134/select-list-in-webform-containing-the-list-of-node-titles)

Comment: Check http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33845/node-reference-field-in-a-webform/91221#91221